# How to make anchor tag work for scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am trying to implement [this](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/pPyZyo) code on my site:

Since it is a WordPress site made with page builder, I had to add all the anchor tags with jquery like this:

```
$('<a name="#A1"></a>').insertBefore('#header');
$('<a name="#A2">Tag #2.</a>').insertBefore('#services');
$('<a name="#A3">Tag #3.</a>').insertBefore('#portfolio');
$('<a name="#A4">Tag #4.</a>').insertBefore('#clients');
```

The code works, but when I try to scroll, nothing happens on the page.
I used this code that you can also see in my [codepen](http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/pPyZyo)

JS:

```
(function() {
  var delay = false;
  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t >= 40) break;
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
        if(t < -20) break;
      }
    }
    $('html,body').animate({
      scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
    });
  });
})();
```

How can I make the jquery Work?

I inspected the site and see this error duplicating everytime I try to scroll.

[image]

[Here](http://www.pinnacle.thedesigners-staging.co.za/) is the site am trying to test.

Comment: Kindly update html code

Comment: Like I mentioned in the question, the site was made with WordPress page builder. That is why I did not post the html and had to add the anchor tags with jquery. But you can see the html if you use your inspector actually.

Answer (score 0):

It is throwing error on this line of code -

```
var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
```

because a[i] for

```
   <a href="#" class="zn-res-trigger zn-menuBurger zn-menuBurger--3--s zn-
        menuBurger--anim1" id="zn-res-trigger">
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </a>
```

don't have getClientRects() method.

So replace your code with

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
    if(!a[i].className.includes('zn-res-trigger')) //add this check{
     var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
    ...........
    }
}
```

Also check with the help of debugger, may be there are other unused anchor tags, so you have to include check for them also

Comment: Am struggling to reajust in my code. My sending your entire js?

Comment: do you want me to add code in js code that you have pasted in your question?

Comment: I edited as per advised as you can see in my updated pen but on the live site it does not work still.
Here the pen: http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/pPyZyo

Comment: You have to add in both the places, in if and else, you have added the above code in else only.

Comment: I thought it was that too but when I refreshed my pen it actually does not work

Comment: The result on the live site is still the same. nothing happens

Answer (score 0):

You have some `a` element that does not have top property which cause the undefined error.

try the bellow code in which I do check the `a[i].getClientRects().length` in order to get the top value :

```
(function() {
  var delay = false;
  $(document).on('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    if(delay) return;

    delay = true;
    setTimeout(function(){delay = false},200)

    var wd = event.originalEvent.wheelDelta || -event.originalEvent.detail;

    var a= document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var scroll = false;
    if(wd < 0) {
      for(var i = 0 ; i < a.length ; i++) {
        if(a[i].getClientRects().length>0) {
           scroll = true;
           var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
           if(t >= 40) break;
        } 
      }
    }
    else {
      for(var i = a.length-1 ; i >= 0 ; i--) {
        if(a[i].getClientRects().length>0) {
           scroll = true;
           var t = a[i].getClientRects()[0].top;
           if(t < -20) break;
        }
      }
    }

    if(scroll){
      $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: a[i].offsetTop
      });
    }
  });
})();
```

Comment: I do not quite follow. The JavaScript works on my codepen, but not on the live site.

Comment: Have you tried my suggestion ?
know that in your case inside the for loop you get the `a` (`a[i].getClientRects()[0].top`) top value , and you have an a element in which it's div's css is set to display:none (div with classname `zn-res-menuwrapper`) ! so `a[i].getClientRects()[0]` will return `undefined` and getting top property of undefined will cause an exeption .

Comment: I tried using exactly the code you sent. Which works on my pen only.
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/pPyZyo

Comment: The error is the same as the one in posted question.

Comment: could you reproduce your template in [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue) , so we can give the right code